# Dao as a Seperate Module in Monolithic Considering Extendable to microservice in future

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I am actually creating one project where we are having 2 or more database. I will use Spring Boot. I would like to know:

1. Why do we have Client of the Gateways while code as we already have REST endpoint in server (May be i am wrong )?
2. My project currently will be monolithic but I want to make it possible to change to a microservice architecture in the future. Should I have the DAO as separate module which will be dependency for other module considering I can have more than one database (RDBMS and NoSQL)?

Hope I am asking work question, but I am confused right now, while starting the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. We do? Let's see it then? What are "Client of the Gateways"? 2) Is it monolithic if you modularize it now? What do you gain by doing so, if you aren't making it a microservice? What is your proposed modular demarcation? RDBMS like SQL? Did you know nosql *means* **Not** **Only** SQL? Your questions are both broad and confusing.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch May be it is confused , I am actually having 2 or more databases , like RDBMS and Mongodb for different purpose, Right now it will be monolithic as we dont know how much customer base we will have so we are thinking to start it as monolithic and will basically modular it as it can be extensible to microservice . about point 1) i have seen that we have a server gateway and a client of the server which is basically exposed to outer world . what if i will expose the endpoint of server as it also have the rest end points.

Comment: 1) I still don't know what you're asking. Who is we? Ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to clear some of the confusion.

You are building MONOLITHIC application using Spring Boot but want it to be microservice ready, RIGHT..

First break your application logically into diff. services and define what data(sql tables) is owned by each service  (every service should have its own DB URL instance , they all might point to same physical DB). Then from one service code you should not access any DB Entity which other service own, when you need data owned by other service then call them their REST API.

Now while doing this you will get stuck in things like where you want to do operations which span multiple services but you want transactional consistency. For eg: on creation of user , user wallet should be created, but user and user wallet should be diff. service.For this you will need to use messaging bus and create user wallet based on the event of user creation.

The solution i currently provided is a very very abstracted and basic view for implementing microservices.This is just for understanding.

I think lots of your questions will be un-answered still. Now ask more specific questions and i will help

Comment: thanks man , Most of the things are cleared now , Will get back to you once have any issue .